# empty check for multiple form in a page separately

Tags: javascript

I have two forms (consist with input,textarea,checkbox) in a page. I want check emptiness of these forms separately on click seperate button.
I use the following script. But it shows empty message if any of these form input is empty.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    var empty = false;

    $('input, textarea').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            empty = true;
        }
    });

    if (empty) {
        alert("empty");
        e.preventDefault();
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById("contact").submit();
    }
})()
```

Comment: *empty check*? what does that mean?

Comment: Of course it does. You set `empty = true;` if any of the textareas is empty. What did you expect? Did you want the opposite logic? (set `empty = false;` if any of them is non-empty?)

Comment: I have two forms. If I submit one form, another form input could be empty.
SO it prevents me from submission. I want check form inputs, textareas empty field seperately

Comment: you have two forms but you only submit a form with ID="contact" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrain the handler to the form containing the clicked button:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    var empty = false;

    $('input, textarea', form).each(function() {

    // the rest is the same
```

I'd also like to point out that you cannot have the same ID on multiple controls, so

```
$('#submit')
```

should always return exactly *one* button. You should do something like this, where you distinguish the buttons by `class` instead:

```
<input type="submit" id="submitA" class="submitButton">
<input type="submit" id="submitB" class="submitButton">
```

and select with

```
$('.submitButton')
```

Comment: or not use the click event at all but use the submit event of the form.

Comment: is form:first means first form of the page

Answer (score 2):

- Never assign stuff to submit buttons
- Do not submit a form from a submit button if you have chosen to use  preventDefault if something wrong. It could submit the form twice

```js
$(function() {
  // on the submit event NOT the button click
  $('form').on("submit", function(e) { // any form - use .formClass if necessary to specific forms
    var empty = false; 
    $("input, textarea", this).each(function() { // this form's inputs incl submit
      if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") { // trim it too
        console.log(this.name,"empty")
        empty = true;
        return false; // no need to continue
      }
    });
    if (empty) {
      alert(this.id + " is empty"); // or set a class on the div
      e.preventDefault(); // cancel submission
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="" name="field1" /><br/>
    <textarea name="field2"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>

<hr/>
<form id="form2">
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="" name="field3" /><br/>
    <textarea name="field4"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

You could also add `required` to the fields

Comment: here $('form') indicate form id or form name?

Comment: @iftekhar143 - I simplified the code - the $("form") is any form and the `,this)` selects only that form's fields

Comment: @iftekhar143 I added (e) which I missed and also gave the submit button a value - I could have done input[type="text"]

Answer (score 0):

you know you can also use jquery to reset the form like so

```
form.resetForm();
```